# Java Transform class in Cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, transform

I am trying to use Transform annotation in a step def:

```
@Given("^I get all the data at once ([^\"]*)$")
public void i_get_all_the_data_at_once(@Transform(StringConcatenaterTransform.class) String allData) {
}
```

My Transform class is like:

```
public class StringConcatenaterTransform extends Transformer<List<String>> {

@Override
public List<String> transform(String value) {
    List<String> listValue = Arrays.asList(value.split(", "));
    List<String> readyForQuery = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listValue.size(); i++ ) {
        //readyForQuery.add(otsParams.get(i));
        readyForQuery.add(listValue.get(i));
    }
    return readyForQuery;
}
```

}

whenever I try to run the suit I get this error message:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to invoke yourStepDef Class
```

can someone tell me what is wrong with my Transform class?

Comment: The step definition method argument should be `List<String> allData` instead of `String`

Comment: Thank you! It has been resolved. For whatever reason I though the incoming type, in my case String, should be passed to Step Definition.